# Inconsistency in numbers between json Marshall and Unmarshall in Golang

Tags: json, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func t() {
    a := int64(1<<63 - 1)
    fmt.Println(a)
    m := map[string]interface{}{
        "balance": a,
    }

    data, _ := json.Marshal(m)
    m1 := make(map[string]interface{})
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &m1)
    panicIF(err)
    fmt.Println(int64(m1["balance"].(float64)))
}

func panicIF(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Running above code will print:

```
9223372036854775807
-9223372036854775808
```

Can you please explain the issue? I read somewhere that in JSON we should not use numbers > 2^53 with number type, rather it should be string type.

Comment: This question seems to be set up to deliberately show the error, but if that is the case then why ask the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When unmarshaling into a map of type `map[string]any`, the [`encoding/json`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json) package will choose `float64` type to unmarshal numbers.

The number `9223372036854775807` cannot be represented precisely by a value of type `float64`, so some other number close to it will be represented, here namely `9223372036854775808.0`. When you convert this number to `int64`, since it is outside of the valid range of `int64`, the result will obviously be something else, in your case the minimum of the representable `int64` values.

Add some extra logging statements:

```
data, err := json.Marshal(m)
panicIF(err)
fmt.Println(string(data))
m1 := make(map[string]interface{})
err = json.Unmarshal(data, &m1)
panicIF(err)
fmt.Println(m1)
fmt.Printf("%f\n", m1["balance"].(float64))
fmt.Println(int64(m1["balance"].(float64)))
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://map%5Bbalance:9.223372036854776e+18%5D%209223372036854775808.000000%20-9223372036854775808)):

```
9223372036854775807
{"balance":9223372036854775807}
map[balance:9.223372036854776e+18]
9223372036854775808.000000
-9223372036854775808
```